# Babel errors when using npm package in React Native application

Tags: javascript, npm, react-native

I am building a React Native application.

I have tried using the following as an npm package in my application: https://github.com/MagicTheGathering/mtg-sdk-javascript/

I try to import the package into one of my files using: `import { card } from 'mtgsdk';` and many other variations of import statements but none have worked.

I get the error:

> TransformError: /myproject/node_modules/mtgsdk/lib/index.js: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory /myproject/node_modules_mtgsdk

What is the right way to import this package into my project? What knowledge is it that I lack about imports in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Your babel doesn't know what exactly plugins you're going to use.

So you should add [.babelrc](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/) file to the root of your project with next configuration:

```
{
  presets: ["es2015"]
}
```

Oh, and dont forget about

```
npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev
```

I hope it'll help

Comment: I think there is something wrong with my import statement as I am somewhat guessing. The project readme says that the package should be imported using const mtg = require('mtgsdk'). Your solution fixes the immediate problem, but then I get SyntaxError /myrpoject/src/app.js: Missing class properties transform.

Comment: @user1283776, you should try to import this module without braces ;)